# Understanding Transactions in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, transactions, transactionscope

Hi I am trying to use transactions along with Entity Framework. With so much information available online on the different ways to implement transactions I must say I am a bit confused on the right way. I have an example database with two tables Employee and Company. The Employee table has a foreign key referring to the company Id. Considering I want to implement a transaction where I insert a record to the Company table and then a record to the Employee table and I want to do this so that records are inserted only if both are successful I have the following code.

```
public void addCompanyToDatabase()
    {
        using (var context = new myTestEntities())
        {
            context.Connection.Open(); //added this as was getting the underlying   
            //provider failed to open
            using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
            {
                try
                {
                    Company c = new Company();
                    c.Name = "xyz";
                    context.Companies.AddObject(c);
                    context.SaveChanges();

                    //int a = 0;
                    //int b = 5 / a;

                    Employee e = new Employee();
                    e.Age = 15;
                    e.Name = "James";
                    e.CompanyId = c.Id;
                    context.Employees.AddObject(e);
                    context.SaveChanges();

                    scope.Complete();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Exception Occurred");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I wanted to know if this was the right way of implementing transactions. If it is then what is the use of the `SaveChanges(false)` and the `scope.AcceptAllChanges()` functions. Any information would be helpful.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your case you don't need to manage any connection or transaction: Entity Framework will do this for you. When you don't supply EF with an opened connection (but with a connection string), it will open a connection and start a transaction during the call to `context.SaveChanges()`. When something fails during that call, the transaction will be rolled back.

In other words, your method can simply look like this:

```
public void addCompanyToDatabase()
{
    using (var context = new myTestEntities())
    {
        Company c = new Company();
        c.Name = "xyz";
        context.Companies.AddObject(c);

        Employee e = new Employee();
        e.Age = 15;
        e.Name = "James";
        e.CompanyId = c.Id;
        context.Employees.AddObject(e);

        // Only call SaveChanges last.
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: That makes sense in case of my example. Can you give me an example where I would need a transaction though? and if the code I mentioned above is the way to go about implementing a transaction? I guess updating records with two different contexts is one scenario.

Comment: The most common case I've encountered that makes you need a transaction, is when you need to call `SaveChanges` multiple times. This can happen when you need the (database generated) id of a new object, or when you need to force the ORM to execute operations in a certain order (for instance, LINQ to SQL tends to reorder deletes after inserts, but this may trigger a database constraint exception).

Comment: In all cases, there is still no need to use a `TransactionScope`. If you need a `TransactionScope` because you need operations to be atomic over multiple database, you have probably have a design flaw in your system. I use `TransactionScope`s purely for my automated integration tests. Just rap the calling code in a `TransactionScope` and you can make sure that all (database) changes are rolled back at the end of the test, without having to alter any code for this.

Answer (score 0):

1-this **service**(i think transaction service) must be **run** in client to support TransactionScope

2-Usefull when you have **tow or more databases** in your application and you want all databases update transactional(such as change connection string of your context).

3-When you have a database is better use SaveChanges() that internally implement transaction.